# how to know which time is working in Cronjob?

Tags: linux, cron

I have the following cron job command :

```
00 4 * * * crontab -e /home/username/public_html/codes/php1.sh
```

and it does not trigger at this time.
I want to know what is the time that the server is depend on it when dealing with cron jobs is it server time or GMT ??
please help me on this I know nothing about cronjobs
P:S 4:00 on my server is 10:00 GMT

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the timezone for cron in `/etc/default/cron`. Set `TZ="$TIMEZONE"`.